# JavaScript - Object.keys() - Access arrays/objects within top-level object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Title might be confusing but couldn't think of any other way to word it.

I've got a function that finds the value of each property within a contact object and returns '*No Data*' if the value is null/empty/undefined, but within each contact object there is an 'Addresses' array with address objects, where I need to access the first/[0] index using a similar method so that I don't have to manually create functions to search the values of each addressLine1, addressLine2 etc. property.

So basically, I need to return '*No Data*' where the values of addressLine1, addressLine2 etc. are empty.

Each object looks something like this:

```
'Items': [
  {
    'property1': 'propertyValue',
    'property2': 'propertyValue',
    'property3': 'propertyValue',
    'addresses': [
      {
        'addressLine1': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine2': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine3': 'propertyValue',
      },
      {
        'addressLine1': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine2': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine3': 'propertyValue',
      },
      {
        'addressLine1': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine2': 'propertyValue',
        'addressLine3': 'propertyValue',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Code that I've currently got to access top level property values looks like this:

```
items.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (property) {
        if (obj[property] === '' || obj[property] === null || obj[property] === undefined) {
            obj[property] = '*No Data*';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good usecase for recursion:

```
(function nodata(items){
 items.forEach(function(obj) {
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (property) {
    if (!obj[property]) {
        obj[property] = '*No Data*';
    }
    if(obj.adresses){
      nodata(obj.adresses);
    }
 });
 });
})(items);
```